# Probability of an inequality

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X_i,i=1,2,3$  are three iid standard normal , variates ,I want to compute  the probability that
$$X_1^2 \geq 4 X_2X_3, $$
I would be highly obliged for any help/hints

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ? But as always, $$\mathbb P\{(X_1,X_2,X_3)\in A\}=\iiint_A f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3)\,\mathrm d x_1\,\mathrm d x_2\,\mathrm d x_3,$$ where $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$ is the joint distribution...

Comment: I am stuck at incorporating the inequality and the corresponding region in the integral

Comment: the integral reduces to  $ \iiint_{z^2 \geq 4xy} e^-{(x^2+y^2+z^^2)} dx dy dy$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The region is

\begin{align*}
\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_1^2\geq 4x_1x_2\}=&\{...\mid x_1^2\geq 0, x_2\geq 0,x_3<0\}\\
&\cup \{...\mid x_1^2\geq 0, x_2< 0,x_3\geq 0\}\\
&\cup \{...\mid x_1^2\geq 4x_2x_3, x_2\geq 0,x_3\geq 0\}\\
&\cup \{...\mid x_1^2\leq 4x_2x_3, x_2<0,x_3<0\},
\end{align*}
and the union is disjoint.